# Spherical mapping calculation (UV) for point given on sphere - strange U values

Tags: c++, textures, texture-mapping, uv-mapping

I want to write an spherical mapping for my ray-tracer to generate UV-coordinates for the sphere. The texture applied with that mapping should looks like that:
[image]

I have the sphere that is located at `[0.0f,0.0f,0.0f]` with the `radius` of `20.0f`.

For given `xyz` point on sphere's surface (position where ray from ray-tracer hit the sphere) I calculate the `uv` coordinates with [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping):

```
float u = 0.5f + atan2(point.getX(), point.getZ()) / (2 * PI);
float v = 0.5f - asin(point.getY() / radius) / PI;
```

I decided to output `u` and `v` values to test the mapping.

As for `v` it looks quite ok (values from one pole to another, from `0.0f` to `1.0f`):
[image]

But the `u` does not look so good:
[image]
Shouldn't it be an sphere where color depends on XZ (same for all points on the same longitude, gradually changing from one longitude to another)?

Am I wrong with interpretation of `point`, formula or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The discontinuity at the centerline is because `atan2()` returns a longitude between -π and π.  You divide this by 2π to scale it to between -0.5 and 0.5, then add 0.5 to scale it between 0 and 1.  The result is a value that jumps discontinuously from 0 to 1, similar to how the local time suddenly jumps back by 24 hours as you cross the international date line, and for the same reason.  To get a continuously-shaded sphere, map the value of u to luminance scaled to an even function, or better yet as a hue on the color wheel.